# How to Style ButtonCell in CellTable Gwt?

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

How to Style ButtonCell in CellTable Gwt?

I searched on internet & found 2 solutions:

-Solution 1: use `urColumn.setCelLStyleNames("yourStyleName");` ([Adding style to a ButtonCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967570/adding-style-to-a-buttoncell))

```
ButtonCell nextStepButton=new ButtonCell();
Column<String[], String> nextStepColumn = new Column<String[], String>(nextStepButton) {

        @Override
        public String getValue(String[] oneOrder) {
            return oneOrder[11];
        }
};
nextStepColumn.setCellStyleNames(getView().getRes().css().buttonCell());
```

in CSS

```
.gwtButton, .buttonCell.getButton {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size:small;
  background: black;
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;

}
```

I tried but nothing happened.

-Solution2: modify ButtonCell (https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7044)

```
               ButtonCell nextStepButton=new ButtonCell(){
                    // A native button cell doesn't have the gwt-button class, which makes it
                      // look weird next to other gwt buttons. Fix that here.
                      @Override
                      public void render(
                          final Context context,
                          final SafeHtml data,
                          final SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\" class=\"gwt-Button\" tabindex=\"-1\">");
                        if (data != null) {
                          sb.append(data);
                        }
                        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</button>");
                      }
                };
```

for the solution2, i can see the difference (ie the Style of ButtonCell got changed). However, I don't have "`gwt-Button`" css class but only have "`gwtButton`" css class (see the above css). However, when I change "gwt-Button" to "gwtButton" in the the 2nd code `sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button type=\"button\" class=\"gwtButton\" tabindex=\"-1\">");` then nothing happened.

So, How to style Button cell so that it can pick up the `gwtButton css class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code posted is what you have in your page, you have an error in the selector, unless you did a mistake when copying to your question.

- try changing `.buttonCell.getButton` with `.buttonCell.gwtButton`
- or change `.buttonCell.getButton` with just `.gwtButton`

[EDITED]

Ok, I see the error, you are setting the style to the container of the button, so you have to change your selector. Use this one in your css resource:

```
.gwtButton button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Manolo, thank you for your answer. I tried .buttonCell.gwtButton but nothing happened. I changed to .gwtButton then the style apply to the whole cell not to the button inside the cell, which is not correct. I want just the button inside the cell get "gwtButton" style. U can see the pic of wrong style here http://i.stack.imgur.com/w9LJt.png.

Comment: can you post the html code as you see in the dev-tools or firebug console?

Comment: Hi Manolo, do u mean the actual html/Javascript code? Here is the View Source of the above code (http://i.stack.imgur.com/WyiFk.png). Pls tell me if you mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was creating a custom Button Cell class (say, StyledButtonCell for e.g.) that extends ButtonCell, and overrode the render method to my liking. In my example below, I specify a basic bootstrap button style and also use an additional icon to go with the button text.

Sample code for custom button cell class (derived from base ButtonCell class):

```
public class StyledButtonCell extends ButtonCell{
/**
   * Construct a new StyledButtonCell that will use a {@link SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer}.
   */
  public StyledButtonCell() {
    super(SimpleSafeHtmlRenderer.getInstance());
  }

  @Override
  public void render(Context context, SafeHtml data, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<button class=\"btn btn-default\" type=\"button\" tabindex=\"-1\">");
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("<i class=\"fa fa-refresh\"></i>");
    if (data != null) {
      sb.append(data);
    }
    sb.appendHtmlConstant("</button>");
  }
```

}

Sample reference to the StyledButtonCell while defining gwt table/columns:

```
... new Column<XYZClass, String>(new StyledButtonCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(XYZClass object) {
            return "buttonText_goes_here";
        }
```